# Same package name on different files

Tags: go

There is same package name in different files in the same folder.

```
a.go

package abc

type B struct {
}
```

```
b.go

package abc

func (b *B) Run() {
}
```

Can the function defined in the file `b.go` access `a.go` without importing anything?

What can be the reasoning behind dividing the code into two different files?

Answer (score 4):

Can the function defined in the file b.go access a.go without importing anything? yes

What can be the reasoning behind dividing the code into two different files? This is just a structuring mechanism, for example when the file would become too large otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Public functions/variables in a.go can be accessed by b.go and vice-versa. The main reason why we put them in different files is to keep all related methods and functionalities together.
For eg:
In package employee:

- Combining all use case methods together in a file(let's call its usecase.go)
- Combining all repository methods together in another file(let's call it repository.go)
- Combining all constants/enum like constants in another file(let's call it constants.go)

All these are available under the same domain package employee.
Each file can access other files public variables/functions. Here usecase.go GetEmployeeData() will access repository.go>GetEmployeeForID(ID int)
Similarly, same usecase method GetEmployeeData() will access constants.go constant Employee_Type to decide some logic based on it.

We group things in a file and try making it small and easy to read. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: any method/variable starting with a capital letter is considered as public.

Comment: [That is called exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers), not public. And identifiers need not be exported to be accessible within a package, i.e *all* identifiers in a.go can be used in b.go, not just the exported ones.